# install phpmyadmin error

Tags: apt, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to install `phpmyadmin` on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and type the following commands,
but I get the following error message on either one of the following command.

Anything I can check the configuration for this?
Your help and information is great appreciated,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Comment: Is that the actual command you typed verbatim? Nvm, just incorrect formatting. Either way, run the command it tells you to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open a command line and run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

For once , Linux actually gives you a helpful error message.